# how to pass parameters to PapermillOperator to run job on airflow?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, papermill, airflow

While running airflow job using PapermillOperator dag execution getting failed.

I am having problem in passing parameters to PapermillOperator.

I opened *papermill_operator.py* (packages/airflow/operators/papermill_operator.py) and hardcoded one line to specify papameters

```
def execute(self, context):
        for i in range(len(self.inlets)):
            pm.execute_notebook(self.inlets[i].location, 
                                self.outlets[i].location,
                                parameters = dict(msgs="hello")
                                progress_bar=False, report_mode=True)
```

Then it's working

while the original code is

```
def execute(self, context):
        for i in range(len(self.inlets)):
            pm.execute_notebook(self.inlets[i].location, 
                                self.outlets[i].location,
                                parameters=self.inlets[i].parameters,
                                progress_bar=False, report_mode=True)
```

Tried another solution 
https://github.com/nteract/papermill/issues/324#issuecomment-472446375
it's working fine

My DAG code is

```
import airflow

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.papermill_operator import PapermillOperator

from datetime import timedelta

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),

}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='9', default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='@once',
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=10))

run_this = PapermillOperator(
    task_id="1",
    dag=dag,
    input_nb="/home/exa00112/abc.ipynb",
    output_nb="/home/exa00112/umesh.ipynb",
    parameters = dict("msgs" = "hello")
)

run_this
```

> [2019-09-10 20:36:48,806] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-09-10 > > > 20:36:48,806] {datasets.py:62} INFO - parameters
>   [2019-09-10 20:36:48,806] {**init**.py:1580} ERROR - Can't compile non > template nodes
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/models/**init**.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
>       result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/operators/papermill_operator.py", line 63, in execute
>       parameters=self.inlets[i].parameters,
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/lineage/datasets.py", line 66, in **getattr**
>       return env.from_string(self._data.get(attr)).render(**self.context)
>    File "/home/exa00112/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 880, in from_string
>       return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
>     File "/home/exa00112/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 581, in compile
>       defer_init=defer_init)
>     File "/home/exa00112/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 543, in _generate
>       optimized=self.optimized)
>     File "/home/exa00112/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/compiler.py", line 78, in generate
>       raise TypeError('Can\'t compile non template nodes')
>   TypeError: Can't compile non template nodes
>   [2019-09-10 20:36:48,808] {**init**.py:1611} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a known issue for the Papermill Operator passing an invalid parameters data structure to Papermill (passing a string parameters dict when papermill looks for a dict) to

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-5774

Not sure on when it will be fixed, as it looks like it's a duplicate issue, so hard to track